# How to run a PHP file on my computer that is outside the htdocs directory?

Tags: php, apache2, htdocs

I just installed Apache and PHP on my computer to be able to run PHP files locally.

I can run a PHP file if it is located in `Apache2.2\htdocs` directory.

Is that possible to run PHP files outside this directory ?

I'm looking to a simple solution, because all I need is to write a small PHP code and try it locally.

I would like to be able to run the PHP file by right clicking it -> Open with Firefox

Comment: `all I need is to write a small PHP code and try it locally.` well, what's wrong with testing it in the Apache2.2\htdocs directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some ways to do it, but the simplest way is using 'include' or 'required' php command:

```
<?
include ('/somewhere/outside/of/your/htdocs/file.php');
?>
```

Please note you may need to turn off 'open_basedir' php directive.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a PHP script from anywhere using the command line:

```
php yourscript.php
```

Comment: I would like to be able to run the PHP file by right clicking it -> Open with Firefox. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Misha - That probably won't work, even if the PHP is in the htdocs directory.  The file must be run and served by the webserver, not interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of php come with php-cli: a command line interface. So to run php code, you just need to type:

```
 php some_code.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can change paths in apache config to another dir

Answer (score 1):

you cannot open it with firefox.
Because firefox has nothing to do win PHP.
So, you need to request this URL from a web-server

Create a windows shortcut with http://127.0.0.1/file.php

or whatever way you prefer to click web links

Comment: @Misha Moroshko: Go to the web page in Firefox and then drag the "fav icon" (the icon to the left of the url) to your desktop. Now, when you double-click it, it will open the url in your browser. This will require you to have your web server running, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You don't say if you want to run it from the web server, or from the command line, but you can use `include` past the web root.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run it from the command line,

or you can create a "wrapper" script within your htdocs that "includes" the file from outside of the htdocs directory

Answer (score 0):

I had always wondered about it the same manner, say you have a folder in a drive either than the apache/htdocs folder in drive C, and you would like to develop directly in this folder. But think about it this way, would you put your folders else where and expect it to be running on the web? Now Way. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Goto **conf** folder and **open httpd** file  change 
**DocumentRoot** "C:/your/path" and 
**Directory** "C:/your/path"
This should work

if it says forbidden access go to this link

[Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)