# Using PHP through XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

In order to run a PHP file using XAMPP, the php file must be saved within C:\xampp\htdocs\new_folder, I was wondering if there is anyway to run PHP by being able to save the PHP file anywhere on my computer and run it by just clicking on it (e.g. location:Desktop).

Comment: you can associate .php files with php.exe, if xampp's installed the CLI copy of php.

Answer (score 1):

**Following solution if you want to run them in your browser, not just with php.exe**

You can define a new host in your hosts file, e.g. test.intern for your localhost, than in your apache httpd.conf set up a virtual host (with e.g. your desktop as destination), and you can run your php file in your browser with your new host as url:

```
test.intern/yourPhpFile.php
```

Detailed manual you can find here:

http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

**PS:** Starting it with doubleclick may be a little tricky, but I just found a solution here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,62530,112860

They do it by creating a shortcut from their browser on their desktop, and add some startparameters to it, so that it directly navigates to `host/youPhpFile.php`, but I don't think you really want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

your files are being run not by xampp but by php.exe file :) if you click php file and choose "open with" and then pick that executable you will be able to run that script (although you could not see any output from that script so real question is: why you want to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that there isn't a great way to do this, but here are some (rather clumsy) options:

[How to run a PHP file on my computer that is outside the htdocs directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975027/how-to-run-a-php-file-on-my-computer-that-is-outside-the-htdocs-directory)